# Can you override Swagger's format for a class / struct

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

I'm using Swagger with an Asp.Net Core web api project but having issues with DateOnly items in the body of an API request.

The model used for the API is

```cs
public record Meeting(
    DateOnly MeetingDate,
    string Agenda);
```

I have written a JsonConverter that is included in the options for Asp.Net so the DateOnly is serialized to / from ISO-8601 calendar date format, i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The problem is that Swagger's examples in swagger-ui for DateOnly properties appear as

```json
"meetingDate": {
        "year": 0,
        "month": 0,
        "day": 0
      }
```

Is there a way to tell Swagger to use ISO-8601 format when documenting DateOnly properties?

For clarification, the API works if ISO-8601 format is passed through Swagger but if you use Swagger's example, it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can map the DateOnly datatype to string like this.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c=>
{
   c.MapType<DateOnly>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "date" });
});
```

Comment: Superb - does exactly what I was looking for 